# pd.to_datetime() changing datetime format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a DataFrame with a str column of dates like

```
'time': '2018-02-25T08:00:00.000Z'
```

but when applying pd.to_datetime to that column, the output looks like

```
'time': '2018-02-25 08:00:00+00:00'
```

Why is the format changing? I tried

```
pd.to_datetime(utc = True)
```

and

```
pd.to_datetime(..., format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

but none of them seem to work and the format gets changed.

Comment: Because it's a `datetime` and not a string? I don't understand the problem

Comment: @roganjosh I want to keep the format and just transform it from str to datetime. Or at least, be able to transform it back from the datetime to the original format as a string, but can't make it work either.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense and I suspect you're missing something. `'2018-02-25T08:00:00.000Z'` is a _string_. What you _get back from_ `pd.to_datetime()` is a `datetime` and the formatting is irrelevant because it's not a string anymore, it has a different representation. If you want to display it back in the same format then you need `.dt.strftime()` on the column

Answer (score 1):

Following @roganjosh comments, I converted it back to string with

```
df['time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
```

Comment: It was already in that format, so why bother converting it to datetime just to convert it back? data validation?